# How to resolve mv cannot stat No such file or directory error

Tags: bash

I need to write a bash script. I have a main folder named ABC and the folder contains multiple folders and each folder has multiple files. Now some of the files are named as _servicename_List.java Here `_servicename_` is acting as a placeholder. I need to replace this placeholder with a string that say `XYZ`

I have tried the below solution However It's not working

```
$Service_Name="XYZ"
cd ABC
for FileName in **/*; do
    mv -- "$FileName" "${FileName/_servicename_/$Service_Name}"
done
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
mv: cannot stat '**/*': No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me with the missing part?
Appreciate all your help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use `**` in a glob pattern. By default, this is disabled (you can check it by doing a `shopt globstar`; in your script, it will likely respond with *globstar off*. You can turn it on with

```
shopt -s globstar
```